# Unreported exception FileNotFoundException in reading a file

Tags: java, user-interface

I was trying to read a file opened using JFileChooser and I got the following errors

```
error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Here's the code snippet:

```
    class LoadFile implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            File f = new File("/home/ralf/Documents");
            String line = null;

            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(f);

            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();              
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

               try {
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fnfe.getMessage());
                    return;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }               
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Note: class LoadFile is found within class Animation(not shown) that extends JFrame. I placed the buttons in the class Animation consructor and from there called LoadFile's actionPerformed.

Comment: I guess JFileChooser itself find the file path..once you select or browse for the file. you dont need to explicitly mention File parameter to its currentDirectory!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you were trying to create a `BufferedReader` outside the `try-catch` block and because `actionPerformed` can't throw any type of exception, the compiler is complaining

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {        
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fnfe.getMessage());
    return;
} catch (IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        // Best effort to close the reader...
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {}
}
```

You're also not closing the reader when you're done with it.  Golden rule, if you open it, you must close it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `BufferedWriter` initialization statement must be in a `try` and `catch` block as well. This is due to the fact that when you create a new `FileWriter` object, it throws an `IOException` which has to be handled under a `try` and `catch` block. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File%29) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
class LoadFile implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        File f = new File("/home/ralf/Documents");
        String line = null;

        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(f);

        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();      
            try {        
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fnfe.getMessage());
                return;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }               
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Your `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));` statement was outside the try-catch block, which prompted it to tell you to either catch or throw it

Answer (score 0):

Move the BufferedReader line into the try-catch block.

```
try {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
     }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fnfe.getMessage());
        return;
     }
```